# Could the signature of a JWT/JWS be used as a globally unique identifier?

Tags: jwt, uuid, jws

In other words, is a signature on a JWT or JWS always unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on *what* the signature should uniquely identify and which signature algorithm you use. A signature is unique in the sense that you when you change anything in the header or payload, the signature also changes (assuming the cryptography works as intended). In other words, JWS tokens with different headers or payloads never have the same signature. However, there can be multiple valid signatures for the same header and payload, depending on whether the signature algorithm is deterministic.

- If the signature is an HMAC, then signing the same data with the same secret results in the same signature.
- If the signature is calculated with (EC)DSA, then [it can be deterministic](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6979), but it might also be randomized.
- If the signature is RSA, there are two different signature schemes, the newer RSASSA-PSS and the older RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. The first one is randomized and therefore different each time, the second is deterministic and therefore the same for the same data.

Comment: ECDSA _can_ use RFC 6979 deterministic signatures, which are a best practice.  However, they are not obligatory, so it may very well change every time (or not), depending on the signing implementation.

Comment: You're right, I've fixed that part.